# request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") wrong when going to myEclipse from JBuilder2008

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

When working with JBuilder2008 my project would build successfully. I changed to MyEclipse and found the following issue:

`request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` has got a red line below `setCharacterEncoding` and it has below problem message:

> The method setCharacterEncoding(String) is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Could you tell me what shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that your Eclipse is configured to use an older version of the servlet APIs; see this [forum post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=405861).  (Right at the end.)  The method is certainly present in the Java Servlet 2.4 APIs.

(FWIW, I pick up my Java Servlet APIs via an explicit Maven dependency, so I'm not hostage to the default version implied by my IDE settings.)

Comment: tank you for your attention, but my problem is immutable yet.
I think its better to have some comment about my changes.first of all its better to say that I have changed my server to WebLogic10.x from webLogic 8.x ,  and you have better to know that I have generated Hibernate from my tables. 
I hope to find the best soloution about my problem.
thank you for your attention and helping and advising me.

Comment: please give me answer for my question and problem, wich I have writen at blow lines.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can.  I use plain Eclipse (not MyEclipse) and I pick up my Servlet APIs from Maven.  I'll retag this question and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside  MyEclipse IDE, please add 'javaee.jar' in your Project's build-path. This will solve your mentioned  error about "request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") "

Usually, during run-time (within web-server container) this jar will be already in classpath. But during development inside IDE, you may face this compile time error.

You will find this JAR at  path depending upon your installation path:For example,

```
C:\MyEclipse6.0\myeclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.genuitec.eclipse.j2eedt.core_6.0.0.zmyeclipse60020070820\data\libraryset\EE_5
```